# How can I set two kind of comparator (one for insert, one for find) on this multiset?

Tags: c++, stl, comparator

I have declared this STL `multiset`:

```
multiset<IMidiMsgExt, IMidiMsgExtComp> playingNotes;
```

and my comparator is:

```
struct IMidiMsgExtComp {
    bool operator()(const IMidiMsgExt& lhs, const IMidiMsgExt& rhs) {
        return lhs.mTick < rhs.mTick;
    }
};
```

and this serves to me well on `.insert`:

```
playingNotes.insert(midiMessage);
```

it inserts (and than orders) the item having the min `mTick` at the top and the max `mTick` in the bottom of the list. So its ordered by `mTick`, and every `.begin()` will return a `IMidiMsgExt` object with the min `mTick` value.

Now, I'd like to find inside this list the first element that have, on another field called `mNote` (which is `int`), the value `60`, and than remove it:

```
auto iteratorItemFound = playingNotes.find(60);
playingNotes.erase(iteratorItemFound );
```

but how can I define on which field the list should search? Another comparator?

Comment: you can use `boost::multi_index` array for that, or implement that manually, unless you want to do linear search

Comment: I see the update to the question. multi_index is one way, or a sorted vector might be another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

```
int value = 60;
auto iteratorItemFound = std::find_if(std::begin(playingNotes), std::end(playingNotes), [value](const IMidiMsgExt& msg)
{
    return msg.mNote == value;
});
```

Comment: find_if has linear search time. it defeats the object of using a map.

Comment: How can I pass that `60` value? Its in a variable outside that scope.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your follow up question but I have to agree with @Richard Hodges.

Comment: @RichardHodges `multiset` is ordered. You're thinking of `unordered_multiset`.

Comment: @JonathanMee; what if I copy elements I need on another list and I change its Comparator? Such as 

struct IMidiMsgExtCompByNote {
 bool operator()(const IMidiMsgExt& lhs, const IMidiMsgExt& rhs) {
  return lhs.mNote() < rhs.mNote();
 }
};

Comment: You cannot change a `multiset`'s comparator, that's part of it's type. But if you were to copy the elements to a new `multiset` which used a different comparator that would be legal.

Comment: Yes, I can insert "temporanely" elements that I'll to search on another multiset. How would you define that comp? So that I can search on it by `mNote`.

Comment: @JonathanMee his search predicate is based on a different property of the midi message to the sorting. He's sorting by time, but deleting by note value.

Comment: @RichardHodges: yes. But I can have a list that insert by time, and a new one (which I populate dynamically) that could be by note value. How would you set this new one multiset/comparator? Example? If I set the new Comparator I've write in the comment above, when I use `playingNotes.find(60)` it says `'std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<IMidiMsgExt>>> std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<_Kty,_Pr,_Alloc,true>>::find(const IMidiMsgExt &) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const IMidiMsgExt &'`

Comment: @RichardHodges Perhaps the question needs clarification. I took that to mean he wanted to delete the `MidiMsgExt` with the smallest `mTime` that had a `mNote` of 60.

Comment: @JonathanMee: no. I want to delete the first note that has `mNote` of 60. No matter the `mTime` when deleting. That's why I could use two list.

Comment: @paizza So you cannot use `playingNotes` ordering to search for the `MidiMsgExt`. What then are you calling the "first note that has `mNote` of 60"? Are you creating another `multiset` that sorts on another criteria? If so what's that criteria?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to ask :) If I can set two different comparator (one for inserting, which is `mTick`, and one for findm which is `mNote`) than I'll use one list. Else, on the first list (where I add) I can use the comparator I've posted. On another one (which I'll populate with MidiMsgExt objects extracted from the first list) I could use `mNote` as key? So `.find` acts on key?

Comment: I mean: this `struct IMidiMsgExtCompByNoteNumber {
 bool operator()(const IMidiMsgExt& lhs, const IMidiMsgExt& rhs) {
  return lhs.mNote < rhs.mNote;
 }
};` will set as key `mNote` right? And find will search for that key? I've tried but it doesn't works. Maybe I add another question.

Comment: @paizza So you're saying that you want to erase the first `IMidiMsgExt` that was inserted? To do that you'll need a member of `IMidiMsgExt` which keeps track of the order in which the elements were created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110564/discussion-between-paizza-and-jonathan-mee).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible (while keeping the logarithmic search properties of the map). The reason is that the `find` method takes an instance of `key_type`, so even writing a custom comparator which has overloads for comparing your key_type against ints will not work.

The idea of a `key_type` is that it's an immutable and cheap object to construct - i.e. you should be unafraid to treat it as a value that can be copied.

Edit:

Here's how I may approach it.

Synopsis:

1. use a sorted vector (sorted by timestamp) as my 'set'.
2. this allows me to search in logarithmic time, same as a set
3. but I can now search across the set quickly (no pointer de-referencing and good cache locality)

code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct midi_message
{
  midi_message(int timestamp, int note) 
    : _timestamp(timestamp)
    , _note(note)
    {}
  int timestamp() const { return _timestamp; }
  int note() const { return _note; }
private:
  int _timestamp, _note;
};

struct earlier
{
  bool operator()(const midi_message& l, const midi_message& r) const {  
    return l.timestamp() < r.timestamp();
  }

  bool operator()(const midi_message& l, const int& r) const {  
    return l.timestamp() < r;
  }
};

struct midi_messages
{
  // insert messages, keeping the map sorted by timestamp
  void add(midi_message m) {
    auto i = std::lower_bound(std::begin(_data),
                                  std::end(_data),
                                  m.timestamp(),
                                  earlier());

    _data.insert(i, std::move(m));
  }

  bool remove_first_note_like(int note)
  {
    auto i = std::find_if(std::begin(_data), 
                          std::end(_data),
                          [note](auto& msg) 
                          { return msg.note() == note; });
    if (i != std::end(_data)) {
      _data.erase(i);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  std::size_t remove_all_before(int timestamp)
  {
    auto new_begin = std::lower_bound(std::begin(_data),
                                      std::end(_data),
                                      timestamp,
                                      [](auto& msg, auto& timestamp) {
                                        return msg.timestamp() < timestamp;
                                      });
    _data.erase(std::begin(_data), new_begin);
  }

  private:
  std::vector<midi_message> _data;
};

int main()
{
  midi_messages messages;

  messages.add(midi_message(1000, 60));
  messages.add(midi_message(1000, 60));
  messages.add(midi_message(1000, 60));
  messages.add(midi_message(1001, 60));
  messages.add(midi_message(1002, 70));
  messages.add(midi_message(1002, 60));
  messages.remove_first_note_like(60);
  messages.remove_all_before(1001);
}
```

Comment: How would you set the key so? Can't `mNote` become the key? (even if I can have objects with the same key at that point).

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something here. How is `midi_messages` different from a `multiset` They both sort their contents based on a comparator?

Comment: @JonathanMee it's offering the same functionality with (most likely) better performance. In all the tests I have ever run, a sorted vector easily outperforms set/map/multiset/multimap

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with [Mohamad Elghawi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36918911/2642059). But it is incomplete.

Your actual code will use a [`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), just like this:

```
const auto it = find_if(cbegin(playingNotes), cend(playingNotes), [value = int{60}](const auto& i){return i.mNote == value;});

if(it != cend(playingNotes)) {
    playingNotes.erase(it);
}
```

This will remove the `IMidiMsgExt` with the lowest `mTick` value which has an `mNote` of 60 (or whatever `value` was initialized to.) If there are multiple `IMidiMsgExt`s in `playingNotes` that tie for the lowest, the `IMidiMsgExt` that has been in `playingNotes` the longest will be removed.

You're explanation of the problem was a little sparse, so I've created and solved a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here: http://ideone.com/oFQ4rS

Answer (score 0):

Solution with [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html):

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29a93b5d8aa15002)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct IMidiMsgExt
{
  int mTick;
  int mTone;
};

using MidiSet=multi_index_container<
  IMidiMsgExt,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_unique<member<IMidiMsgExt,int,&IMidiMsgExt::mTick>>,
    hashed_non_unique<member<IMidiMsgExt,int,&IMidiMsgExt::mTone>>
  >
>;

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  MidiSet m={{0,100},{2,60},{3,150},{5,60},{1,200},{4,90}};

  std::cout<<"before erasing:\n";
  for(const auto& msg:m)std::cout<<"["<<msg.mTick<<","<<msg.mTone<<"]";
  std::cout<<"\n";

  m.get<1>().erase(60);

  std::cout<<"after erasing:\n";
  for(const auto& msg:m)std::cout<<"["<<msg.mTick<<","<<msg.mTone<<"]";
  std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

Output

```
before erasing:
[0,100][1,200][2,60][3,150][4,90][5,60]
after erasing:
[0,100][1,200][3,150][4,90]
```