# Comparator can be used to set a new key, isn't?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, comparator

I need to change the "key" of a multiset:

```
multiset<IMidiMsgExt, IMidiMsgExtCompByNoteNumber> playingNotes;
```

such as that when I use the `.find()` function it search and return the first object (iterator) with that `NoteNumber` property value.

I said "first" because my multiset list could contains objects with the same "key". So I did:

```
struct IMidiMsgExtCompByNoteNumber {
    bool operator()(const IMidiMsgExt& lhs, const IMidiMsgExt& rhs) {
        return lhs.NoteNumber() < rhs.NoteNumber();
    }
};
```

but when I try to do:

```
auto it = playingNotes.find(60);
```

the compiler says `no instance of overloaded function "std::multiset<_Kty, _Pr, _Alloc>::find [with _Kty=IMidiMsgExt, _Pr=IMidiMsgExtCompByNoteNumber, _Alloc=std::allocator<IMidiMsgExt>]" matches the argument list`

Am I misunderstanding the whole thing? What's wrong?

Comment: Can `60` be converted to a `IMidiMsgExt` as that is what [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/find) expects for an argument?

Comment: Your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918760/how-can-i-set-two-kind-of-comparator-one-for-insert-one-for-find-on-this-mult, seems to have the answer for this question too. No?

Comment: @RSahu: not really! Thats why I've opened this question!

Comment: @NathanOliver: so I need to pass a message "similar" to what I'm looking for? Can't find an object for the value of a field?

Comment: @paizza Yes.  `find` requires a value of type `key`.  You need to supply the `key` you are looking for.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I don't get what You mean. Can you show to me a smart example?

Comment: Whats not to get?  find needs a `IMidiMsgExt` in order to work.

Comment: But I don't have any "IMidiMsgExt". I need one from the list that have fixed value in one of its field :O

Comment: Or are you saying that I can pass a IMidiMsgExt (even if empty, just NoteNumber filled) with that value, and it will return (from the list) the first that have the same value?

Comment: @paizza Yes.  You just need to set the value you are looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110558/discussion-between-paizza-and-nathanoliver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe that you have some misunderstandings here:

1. Part of an [associative container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Associative_containers)'s type is it's key type and comparator. Because C++ is strongly typed the only way to change the comparator on a container is to create a new container, copying or moving all the elements into it
2. Creating a copy of all the elements in a container is a potentially expensive process
3. By creating a copy you are violating the [Single Source of Truth](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/317136/98845) best practice
4. [`multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) is used infrequently, I have used it once in my career, others have pointed out it's shortcomings and recommended that you [use another container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36934049/2642059), [write your own container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36919112/2642059), or in my case I'd suggests simply using [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and sorting it how you want when you have to

I'm going to catalog your comments to show how [the answer I've already given you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36919852/2642059) is correct:

- We're going to assume that the `multiset<IMidiMsgExt, IMidiMsgExtCompByNoteNumber>` that you've selected is necessary and cannot be improved upon by using `vector` as suggested in **4**, where:

```
struct IMidiMsgExtCompByNoteNumber {
    bool operator()(const IMidiMsgExt& lhs, const IMidiMsgExt& rhs) {
        return lhs.NoteNumber() < rhs.NoteNumber();
    }
};
```

- You cannot use [`multiset::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/find) because that requires you tospecify the exact `IMidiMsgExt` you are searching for; so you'll need to use `find_if(cbegin(playingNotes), cend(playingNotes), [value = int{60}](const auto& i){return i.mNote == value;})` to search for a specific property value. Which will be fine to use on to use directly on `PlayingNotes` without changing the sorting, because [you say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918760/how-can-i-set-two-kind-of-comparator-one-for-insert-one-for-find-on-this-mult#comment61401537_36918911):

> I want to delete the first note that has mNote of 60. No matter the mTime when deleting.

- You'll need to capture the result of the [`find_if`], check if it is valid, and if so `erase` it as demonstrated in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36919852/2642059), because [you say](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30231474#30231474):

> The first element find will find for that, erase. [sic]

- I would roll the code from my answer into a function because [you say](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30231484#30231484):

> Ill recall find if I want another element, maybe with same value, to get deleted [sic]

Your final solution should be to write a function like this:

```
bool foo(const multiset<IMidiMsgExt, IMidiMsgExtCompByNoteNumber>& playingNotes, const int value) {
    const auto it = find_if(cbegin(playingNotes), cend(playingNotes), [=](const auto& i){return i.mNote == value;});
    const auto result = it != cend(playingNotes);

    if(result) {
        playingNotes.erase(it);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And you'd call it something like this: `foo(playingNotes, 60)` if you wish to know whether an element was removed you may test `foo`'s return.